# Disable hotlinking or saving or your images online?

Tags: cdn, copyright, business, code

I have some JavaScript and CSS to block right clicks and stuff and everything is on cloudflare CDN which tells me when I get hotlinked.

Is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 3):

Practically speaking, disabling hotlinking can be achieved by looking at the REFERER attribute sent by web browsers and not displaying the image if the REFERER is not approved.

Disabling if images being saved on line is a lot harder. In the ultimate scheme if things it is close to impossible because people can just screen capture your images.   Things like JavaScript can frustrate this but not prevent it.

It might be technically possible to make the images video streams and use DRM technology (like Netflix use [Widevine] ) to frustrate downloading but this is likely super expensive and likely to provide very limited protection and a bad user experience. Remember there is always the "Analog hole" - ie taking a picture of the screen - either literally or figuratively - if someone is desperate enough.

Comment: Exactly, and so I’m kinda set on designing a unique watermark, I don’t have control of my apache server because I host with a “landing page” so it’s multiple pages but one in reality, I’m still trying to figure how to no index certain things to it’s a bit tricky.

Comment: @johnnyt don't understand your comment - but is converting the landing page to (for example) php and having that process/switch/filter the output not an option?